# html navbar button not filling entire space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a jsfiddle html webpage that has a navbar with two buttons. The button on the left is good, but the button on the right has a problem, it doesn't fill up the entire space, and has an empty margin at the bottom. I know this is super simple and probably has a  single css fix, I tried setting the mx-auto and my-auto to set the margin x and margin y to auto, tried adding `display: block;` but still no luck. looking for help please.

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/u03f1zyo/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the icon in the left button, which is stretching the container height. A fix would be to decrease the `font-size` of the icon to say `1.4rem`.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/gdoyv3w7/3/)

Problem is your `2rem` on first element. Once you remove it, it will automatically adjust for both. Otherwise set same for both. Do not adjust one to make the other correct. It will not render on all browsers, devices with different screen size.

```
#newUploadIcon{
  color:rgb(14, 80, 36);
  display: block;
  margin:auto; 
 
  margin-right:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```